# Removing nonnumeric and nonalpha characters from a string?

Tags: regex, string, replace

What is the best way to remove all the special characters from a string - like these:

!@#$%^&*(){}|:"?><,./;'[]\=-

The items having these characters removed would rather short, so would it be better to use REGEX on each or just use string manipulation?

Thx

Environment == C#/.NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in php:

```
$tests = array(
     'hello, world!'
    ,'this is a test'
    ,'and so is this'
    ,'another test with /slashes/ & (parenthesis)'
    ,'l3375p34k stinks'
);

function strip_non_alphanumerics( $subject )
{
    return preg_replace( '/[^a-z0-9]/i', '', $subject );
}

foreach( $tests as $test )
{
    printf( "%s\n", strip_non_alphanumerics( $test ) );
}
```

output would be:

```
helloworld
thisisatest
andsoisthis
anothertestwithslashesparenthesis
l3375p34kstinks
```

Comment: I might add some test cases with capital letters.

Comment: @jm: that's a good thing too, i was just too lazy to type any and the "i" following the regex makes the regex case-insensitive ;)

Comment: P.S. Why is this the accepted answer if the question now states environment to be .NET? (I don't think it did when I answered). It wouldn't be too conceptually different in for example C#, but would look nothing like this.

Answer (score 6):

It's generally better to have a whitelist than a blacklist.

Regex has a convenient `\w` that, effectively means alphanumeric plus underscore (some variants also add accented chars (á,é,ô,etc) to the list, others don't).

You can invert that by using `\W` to mean everything that's not alphanumeric.

So **replace `\W` with empty string will remove all 'special' characters.**

Alternatively, if you do need a different set of characters to alphanumeric, you can use a negated character class: `[^abc]` will match everything that is not `a` or `b` or `c`, and `[^a-z]` will match everything that is not in the range `a,b,c,d...x,y,z`

The equivalent to `\w` is `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and thus `\W` is `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`

Answer (score 2):

I prefer **regex** because the syntax is simpler to read and maintain:

```
# in Python
import re
re.sub("[abcdef]", "", text)
```

where `abcdef` are the *properly escaped* characters to be removed.

Alternatively, if you want only alphanumeric characters (plus the underscore), you could use:

```
re.sub("\W", "", text)
```

where `\W` represents a *non-word character*, i.e. `[^a-zA-Z_0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

When you just want to have alphanumeric characters, you could just express this by using an inverted character class:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9]+
```

This means: every character that is not alphanumeric.

Comment: \w stands for [A-Za-z0-9_] and I’m not sure if he want’s the low line as well.

Answer (score 1):

here's a simple regex

```
[^\w]
```

this should catch all non-word characters this will permit a-z A-Z 0-9 space and _ neither space nor _ were in your list so this works if you wanted to catch these also then I would do something like this:

```
/[a-z0-90/i
```

this is the PHP format for a-z and 0-9 the i makes it case-insensitive.

Comment: This is wrong. \w does *not* include space. It is also overly complex to do "[^\w]" instead of just "\W". And your second expression will not work - it has a zero in place of closing bracket. This is also not a PHP-specific format, it works for many different forms.

Answer (score 0):

Us the "tr" command?

You don't say what enviroment you're in... shell?  C program?  Java?  Each of those would have different best solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In what language are you going the regex?

For example, in Perl you can do a translation which would translate any of the chars in your list into nothing:

e.g. This will translate 'a','b','c' or 'd' into ''

```
$sentence =~ tr/abcd//;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rather validate them at the frontend by getting the askey values of the keyed in characters.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal approach in PHP would be...

```
$text = "ABCDEF...Á123";
$text = preg_replace( '/[^\p{L}]/i', '', $text);
print($text); # Output: ABCDEFÁ
```

Or, in Perl...

```
my $text = "ABCDEF...Á123";
$text =~ s/[^\p{L}]//gi;
print($text); # Output: ABCDEFÁ
```

If you simply match on [^a-zA-Z], you will miss all accented characters, which (for the most part), I imagine you would want to retain.